# How to Get Overlayed Calendars to Keep Their Colors When Viewed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I find the SharePoint calendar options lacking a lot, but I'm hoping it's just a limitation of Foundation or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

I've got a test calendar that looks like this:
[image]

I like the color coding, but when I view one of the calendars being overlayed, the events are displayed in the default color:
[image]

I think that if I could just change each calendar's default color to match the assigned color from the overlay view, it would go a long way to improving the experience.

**What I Have Access To:**

- SharePoint Designer 2013
- Admin Permissions

I'm not a programmer... though I'm not afraid to use some code. If I need to inject some code to make this work, please pleas please be specific as far as where I need to put it and how to access that place.

I read somewhere someone said to edit the view page and add a snippet, but I didn't understand what they meant. Can I edit the code of a view? Or where they talking about creating a whole new page and using an app part?

I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution from some blog posts and other questions.

Turns out that view pages can be edited under the setting menu. There's an edit option there!! WHAT?!
[image]

I've added an HTML Form Web Part and inserted my CSS according to this article:

http://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/